# How to read POST data in PHP from button

Tags: php, html, post

I have a button that depicts delivery or pickup. The code is as follow:

```
$output .= "<button type='submit' name='checkout' value='checkout|delivery''>Delivery</button>\n";
$output .= "<button type='submit' name='checkout' value='checkout|pickup'>Pick Up</button>\n";
```

When I go to the Inspector in Google Chrome, I can see that in Network --> Headers there is a Post with the data that I need.

How can I retrieve the `checkout:checkout|delivery` via PHP?

Comment: `print_r($_POST['checkout']);`

Comment: @anantkumarsingh When I print_r - I don't get any output.When I var_dump($_POST); I get null.

Comment: can you show full code?

Comment: The code you have should work. What does the form start tag look like?

Comment: I updated the whole code for the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve it with this:

```
$_POST['checkout']
```

And in an if-statement:

```
if($_POST['checkout'] == "checkout|delivery"){
    // Should be delivered
} else {
    // Will be picked up
}
```

Comment: I tried this by testing with echo before posting, but I do not get any output. I tried var_dump and print_r and it returns $_POST = null.

Comment: @ABard you have to show your full code of form. then only anyone can say what problem is there.

Comment: Try it with `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`, just in case you missed form method. And please provide the whole form code.

Comment: @RichardReiber I tried with $_REQUEST and still have empty array. In addition, I posted the code for the entire `order_function.php` for review.

Comment: @ABard: I see no problem there... Can you just post the generated page source code?

Comment: @RichardReiber update with source code for both pages. Page 1 sends the form and Page 2 should be receiving the post.

Comment: @ABard: You have  double ' after checkout|delivery

Comment: @RichardReiber I fixed that and tried with pickup that didn't have the extra ' but still no go. - Thanks for your help but I think I'm going to try a different approach.